# Чтение значений одной строки по шаблону другой

Tags: c++, строки

Пытаюсь сделать следующее:
Читаем строку шаблон str2 (которая со звездочками)
Если находим * , то читаем значение из str1 в соотсветствующей позиции если находим & в str2 то обработка строки прекращается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     bool flag = false;
     int start_pos_2 {};
     int start_pos_1 {};
     int counter {};
     int tag_counter {};
     int next_position_1 {};
     std::string make_string {};
     std::string final_string {};
     std::string str1("<tr> <th>Test_Value</th> <th>56</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value_2</th> <th>45</th> </tr>");
     std::string str2("<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>");
     size_t I = str2.find("*");
     tag_counter = std::count(str2.begin(), str2.begin() + I, '>');
     for (; start_pos_1 <= str1.length(), start_pos_2 <= str2.length(); start_pos_1++, start_pos_2++)
     {

           if (counter != tag_counter)
           {
                   if (str1[start_pos_1] == '>')
                   {
                           counter++;
                   } else
                           continue;

           }else
           {
                   if (flag == false)
                   {
                           next_position_1 = start_pos_1;
                           while (str1[next_position_1] != '<')
                           {
                                   make_string += str1[next_position_1];
                                   next_position_1++;
                           }

                           flag = true;
                           make_string += ',';

                           final_string += make_string;
                   } else
                           continue;

           }
     }
    cout << final_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: сейчас программа находит только первую * и читает значение с тойже позиции из другой строки. Как продолжить поиск других * в строке, а также прекратить при нахождении &?

Comment: опишите вашу проблему, в чем вопрос заключается?

Comment: Да, описал что делает программа сейчас и добавил вопрос.

Comment: сейчас набросаю примерный код, никуда не уходи))

Comment: А может использовать регулярки? Хотя, если тут html/xml есть куда более правильные способы

Comment: так как вы работаете с двумя строками, то можете обойтись и одним альгоритмом std::inner_product ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Позволил себе немного вольности в рамках вашей задачи, как я понял, вам нужно считать все значения внутри тегов по какому-то шаблону(правда, через regex, думаю, было бы проще, или скорее всего есть какой-нибудь reader для этих целей, ну да ладно):

```
int main()
{

    std::string make_string{};
    std::string final_string{};
    std::string str1("<tr> <th>Test_Value</th> <th>564</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value2</th> <th>456</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value3</th> <th>123</th> </tr>"); 
    std::string str2("<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>");
    size_t i = 0;
    i = str2.find("*", i);
    int position = i;
    auto count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        while (str1[position] != '<')
        {
            make_string += str1[position];
            position++;
        }

        i = str2.find("*", i + 1);
        if (i > str1.length())
            break;

        final_string += make_string + ',';
        make_string = "";

        count += 2;
        position = i + (final_string.length() - count);
    }
    final_string += make_string;

    cout << final_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: почему вот это вообще срабатывает? i = str2.find("*", i + 1); вродебы говорим что позицию увеличить на 1, а это следующее значение после i

Comment: ну нужно искать **после** крайней *, а не **до**. иначе find будет находить одну и ту же *.

Comment: Если добавить ещё одну строку <tr></tr> или болоьше то все сломалось.

Comment: std::string str1("<tr> <th>Test_Value</th> <th>564</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value2</th> <th>456</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value3</th> <th>123</th> </tr>");
std::string str2("<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>");

Comment: действительно допустил ошибку, смотрите исправленный вариант

Comment: лучше  использовать функции члены класса string  и  стандартные альгоритмы, чем  написать циклы, а потом искать ошибки

Comment: Не могли  бы вы привести псевдокод или названия функций?